# AngularJS - Add directive from within controller

Tags: angularjs, slickgrid

I have defined the following directive:

```
app.directive('copyExpenditure', function(){
          return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: true,
            template: '<button ng-click="copyExpenditure()">click me</button>'
          }
});
```

If I add this directive directly into the html it works as expected.

```
<div copy-expenditure></div>
```

Now I'm creating a grid from within a controller and want to dynamically add to each row the copyExpenditure directive. For this task I'm using [Slickgrid and a custom Formatter](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Column-Options).

```
var LinkFormatter = function (row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    var tag = '<div copy-expenditure></div>';
    return tag;
}
```

But it seems as this custom formatter is not rendered as a directive, but only as HTMl. Any idea what to do? My goal is only to call a scope function using `ng-click` and a tag rendered by the `LinkFormatter`.

Answer (score 0):

You should do:

```
$compile(angular.element('<div copy-expenditure></div>'))($scope);
```

and if you have some values passed into it from scope, you do this after compile:

```
$scope.$digest();
```